# Create top level 'aar' which has multiple aar files as dependencies in gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-library, aar

I have three 'aar' files, with some features.(I have not created those)

Now I created android project(let's say PROJ) and placed those three aar files in libs folder. Now I can access features of those aar files in my Activity of PROJ.

**But my requirement is to use all this as a library**. So I created one aar file from my PROJ. aar file is created successfully.
Now I'm placing this new aar file(created from PROJ) in another android project's lib folder.

But I can't access classes from those three aar files(which I have added as dependency in PROJ). Runtime Exception is thrown as...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "XYZHandler" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.testerapp-dBRDWoDJbcGXhTEN9jvp4g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.testerapp-dBRDWoDJbcGXhTEN9jvp4g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
```

Comment: So you can access that class during compile time ? And do you have the source code of those 3 AAR files ?

Comment: @average_developer No I can't access at compile time. I have source code of those AAR files. But I want to make one AAR file with my code as well as code from those three AAR files.